# Add files in program data using wix

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, windows-installer

I am developing an Outlook addin using addin express. I am using a `.wxs` file in my program's setup project. It helps me to install my program in `roaming` folder. I want to add `Redemption.dll` to the path `C:\programData\Flow`. So I modified the code as mentioned below. But it is not working. Please advice me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <!--Modified[Id]-->
  <Product
  Id="faa8e62a-0834-4efa-aad3-b2f7903a3a6c"
  Name="FlowOutlook"
  Language="1033"
  Version="1.1.4"
  Manufacturer="Default Company"
  UpgradeCode="faa8e62a-0834-4efa-aad3-b2f7903a3a6d"
  Codepage="1252">

    <Package
      InstallerVersion="200"
      Compressed="yes"
      InstallScope="perUser"
      Description="FlowOutlook"
      Manufacturer="Default Company"
      Languages="1033"
      SummaryCodepage="1252"
      InstallPrivileges="limited"
    />

    <!--Added-->
    <Property Id="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" Secure="yes" />
    <Upgrade Id="faa8e62a-0834-4efa-aad3-b2f7903a3a6d">
      <!--Should be same as "UpgradeCode"-->
      <UpgradeVersion
         Minimum="1.0.0" Maximum="1.1.4"
         Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED"
         IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" />
    </Upgrade>

    <!--Romoved-->
    <!--<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />-->
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="FlowOutlook.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="FlowOutlook" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <ComponentRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <!--<ComponentRef Id="Redemption.dll" />-->
      <!--Added-->
    </Feature>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

    <!-- Pics-->
    <!-- Pics-->

    <Binary Id="adxregistrator_exe" SourceFile="$(var.ADX_PATH)\Redistributables\adxregistrator.exe" />

    <CustomAction Id="RegisterApp" BinaryKey="adxregistrator_exe" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand='/install="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetFileName)" /privileges=user /returnExitCode=false' Impersonate="yes" />
    <CustomAction Id="RollbackApp" BinaryKey="adxregistrator_exe" Execute="rollback" ExeCommand='/uninstall="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetFileName)" /privileges=user' Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" />
    <CustomAction Id="UnregisterApp" BinaryKey="adxregistrator_exe" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand='/uninstall="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetFileName)" /privileges=user' Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" />

    <!--Added-->
    <CustomAction Id="RegisterRedemption32" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand='regsvr32.exe "C:\ProgramData\Flow\Redemption.dll"'></CustomAction>
    <!--self registering Redemption 32-bit -->
    <CustomAction Id="UnregisterRedemption32" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand='regsvr32.exe /u "C:\ProgramData\Flow\Redemption.dll"'></CustomAction>
    <!--self unregistering Redemption 32-bit -->
    <CustomAction Id="RegisterRedemption64" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand='regsvr32.exe "C:\ProgramData\Flow\Redemption64.dll"'></CustomAction>
    <!--self registering Redemption 64-bit -->
    <CustomAction Id="UnregisterRedemption64" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand='regsvr32.exe /u "C:\ProgramData\Flow\Redemption64.dll"'></CustomAction>
    <!--self unregistering Redemption 64-bit -->

    <!--Added-->

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="RegisterApp" After="StartServices"><![CDATA[$ProductComponent>2]]></Custom>
      <Custom Action="RollbackApp" After="RegisterApp"><![CDATA[$ProductComponent>2]]></Custom>
      <Custom Action="UnregisterApp" After="MsiUnpublishAssemblies"><![CDATA[$ProductComponent=2]]></Custom>
      <!--Added-->
      <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
      <Custom Action="RegisterRedemption32" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
      <!--self registering Redemption 32-bit-->
      <Custom Action="UnregisterRedemption32" After="InstallFinalize">REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
      <!--self unregistering Redemption 32-bit-->
      <Custom Action="RegisterRedemption64" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
      <!--self registering Redemption 64-bit-->
      <Custom Action="UnregisterRedemption64" After="InstallFinalize">REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
      <!--self unregistering Redemption 64-bit-->
      <!--Added-->
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <!-- Properties for all current versions of the .NET Framework are available here: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm -->
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT"/>
    <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT]]>
    </Condition>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="FlowOutlook" >
          <Component Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="cdca45fb-ce6c-4a00-9865-29b24123c62a">
            <RemoveFolder On="both" Id="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="FlowOutlook" />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR2" Name="SourceDir2">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="Flow"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" >
      <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="2596359b-ed35-42f1-be52-2ff4625189f5" DiskId="1" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" >
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]">
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Installed" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" KeyPath="yes" />
        </RegistryKey>
        <File Id="_$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetName)_dll" Name="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetPath)" />
        <File Id="_adxloader_dll_manifest" Name="adxloader.dll.manifest" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.ProjectDir)Loader\" />
        <File Id="_adxloader_dll" Name="adxloader.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.ProjectDir)Loader\"  />
        <File Id="_adxloader64_dll" Name="adxloader64.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.ProjectDir)Loader\" />
        <File Id="_AddinExpress_MSO_2005_dll" Name="AddinExpress.MSO.2005.dll" Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\Add-in Express\Add-in Express for .NET\Bin\" />
        <File Id="_AddinExpress_OL_2005_dll" Name="AddinExpress.OL.2005.dll" Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\Add-in Express\Add-in Express for .NET\Bin\" />

        <File Id="_Newtonsoft_Json_dll" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir)" />
        <File Id="_Microsoft_Vbe_Interop_dll" Name="Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir)" />
        <File Id="_Newtonsoft_Json_pdb" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.pdb" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir)" />
        <File Id="_Newtonsoft_Json_xml" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.xml" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir)" />
        <File Id="_Redemption_dll" Name="Redemption.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir2)" />
        <File Id="_Newtonsoft_Json_xml" Name="Redemption64.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir2)" />

      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Thanks for helping. Kushan Randima

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it's considered Bad Practice to execute regsvr32 or regasm from the installer. The approach that MS prefer is to extract the registration info from the dll to be registered, and then msiexec itself will make the registry changes. That way, if anything goes wrong msiexec can unwind any changes it made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, I had to create another  element as a child element of  and I had to add some extra code under . Please see below code to see working solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension">
  <!--Modified[Id]-->
  <Product
  Id="faa8e62a-0834-4efa-aad3-b2f7903a3a6c"
  Name="FlowOutlook"
  Language="1033"
  Version="1.1.5"
  Manufacturer="Default Company"
  UpgradeCode="faa8e62a-0834-4efa-aad3-b2f7903a3a6d"
  Codepage="1252">

    <Package
      InstallerVersion="200"
      Compressed="yes"
      InstallScope="perUser"
      Description="FlowOutlook"
      Manufacturer="Default Company"
      Languages="1033"
      SummaryCodepage="1252"
      InstallPrivileges="limited"
    />

    <!--Added-->
    <Property Id="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" Secure="yes" />
    <Upgrade Id="faa8e62a-0834-4efa-aad3-b2f7903a3a6d">
      <!--Should be same as "UpgradeCode"-->
      <UpgradeVersion
         Minimum="1.0.0" Maximum="1.1.5"
         Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED"
         IncludeMinimum="yes" IncludeMaximum="no" />
    </Upgrade>

    <!--Romoved-->
    <!--<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />-->
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="FlowOutlook.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

    <Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="FlowOutlook" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <ComponentRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />

      <!--<ComponentRef Id="Redemption.dll" />-->
      <!--Added-->
    </Feature>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />

    <!-- Pics-->
    <!-- Pics-->

    <Binary Id="adxregistrator_exe" SourceFile="$(var.ADX_PATH)\Redistributables\adxregistrator.exe" />

    <CustomAction Id="RegisterApp" BinaryKey="adxregistrator_exe" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand='/install="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetFileName)" /privileges=user /returnExitCode=false' Impersonate="yes" />
    <CustomAction Id="RollbackApp" BinaryKey="adxregistrator_exe" Execute="rollback" ExeCommand='/uninstall="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetFileName)" /privileges=user' Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" />
    <CustomAction Id="UnregisterApp" BinaryKey="adxregistrator_exe" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand='/uninstall="[INSTALLFOLDER]$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetFileName)" /privileges=user' Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" />

    <!--Added-->
    <!--self registering Redemption 32-bit -->
    <CustomAction Id="RegisterRedemption32" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand='regsvr32.exe /s "C:\ProgramData\Flow\Redemption.dll"'></CustomAction>
    <!--self unregistering Redemption 32-bit -->
    <CustomAction Id="UnregisterRedemption32" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand='regsvr32.exe /s /u "C:\ProgramData\Flow\Redemption.dll"'></CustomAction>
    <!--self registering Redemption 64-bit -->
    <CustomAction Id="RegisterRedemption64" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand='regsvr32.exe /s "C:\ProgramData\Flow\Redemption64.dll"'></CustomAction>
    <!--self unregistering Redemption 64-bit -->
    <CustomAction Id="UnregisterRedemption64" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" ExeCommand='regsvr32.exe /s /u "C:\ProgramData\Flow\Redemption64.dll"'></CustomAction>
    <!--Added-->

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="RegisterApp" After="StartServices"><![CDATA[$ProductComponent>2]]></Custom>
      <Custom Action="RollbackApp" After="RegisterApp"><![CDATA[$ProductComponent>2]]></Custom>
      <Custom Action="UnregisterApp" After="MsiUnpublishAssemblies"><![CDATA[$ProductComponent=2]]></Custom>
      <!--Added-->
      <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
      <!--self registering Redemption 32-bit-->
      <Custom Action="RegisterRedemption32" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
      <!--self unregistering Redemption 32-bit-->
      <Custom Action="UnregisterRedemption32" After="InstallFinalize">REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
      <!--self registering Redemption 64-bit-->
      <Custom Action="RegisterRedemption64" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
      <!--self unregistering Redemption 64-bit-->
      <Custom Action="UnregisterRedemption64" After="InstallFinalize">REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
      <!--Added-->
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <!-- Properties for all current versions of the .NET Framework are available here: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm -->
    <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT"/>
    <Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
      <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENT]]>
    </Condition>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="AppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="FlowOutlook" >
          <Component Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Guid="cdca45fb-ce6c-4a00-9865-29b24123c62a">
            <RemoveFolder On="both" Id="INSTALLFOLDER"/>
            <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="FlowOutlook" />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <!-- Reference the Program Files folder -->      
      <Directory Id="CommonAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONDATADIRECTORY" Name="Flow"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" >
      <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="2596359b-ed35-42f1-be52-2ff4625189f5" DiskId="1" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" >
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]">
          <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Installed" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" KeyPath="yes" />
        </RegistryKey>
        <File Id="_$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetName)_dll" Name="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetPath)" />
        <File Id="_adxloader_dll_manifest" Name="adxloader.dll.manifest" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.ProjectDir)Loader\" />
        <File Id="_adxloader_dll" Name="adxloader.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.ProjectDir)Loader\"  />
        <File Id="_adxloader64_dll" Name="adxloader64.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.ProjectDir)Loader\" />
        <File Id="_AddinExpress_MSO_2005_dll" Name="AddinExpress.MSO.2005.dll" Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\Add-in Express\Add-in Express for .NET\Bin\" />
        <File Id="_AddinExpress_OL_2005_dll" Name="AddinExpress.OL.2005.dll" Source="C:\Program Files (x86)\Add-in Express\Add-in Express for .NET\Bin\" />
        <File Id="_Newtonsoft_Json_dll" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir)" />
        <File Id="_Microsoft_Vbe_Interop_dll" Name="Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir)" />
        <File Id="_Newtonsoft_Json_pdb" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.pdb" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir)" />
        <File Id="_Newtonsoft_Json_xml" Name="Newtonsoft.Json.xml" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir)" />
      </Component>     
      <Component Id="ProductComponent2" Guid="2596359b-ed35-42f1-be52-2ff4625189f6" DiskId="1" Directory="APPLICATIONDATADIRECTORY" >      
        <File Id="_Redemption_dll" Name="Redemption.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir)" />
        <File Id="_Redemption64.dll" Name="Redemption64.dll" Source="$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir)" />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

The C:\ drive requires admin privileges for writing. You need to run the installer elevated (Run As Admin).

Comment: I have done something wrong in the code. It doesn't compile the solution. I will be worry about the permission issues later on. Thanks for reminding me that.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What errors do you get if VS doesn't compile your source code?

Comment: It doesn't allow me to create another directory (rather than the directory that I use to install my pluggin) with the ID of "TARGETDIR". But it doesn't allow me to use another ID either. [The error is "Undefined preprocessor variable'$(var.FlowOutlook.TargetDir2)'"]

Comment: You don't need targetdir2 as far as I can tell. Just install your Dll in CommonAppDataFolder \ Flow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Windows Installer property [CommonAppDataFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367992(v=vs.85).aspx) in a directory element that is a child of the TARGETDIR directory element.  Then create a child directory element beneath this for your company name and use this directory element in your component authoring.

FWIW I maintain an open source project called [ISWIX](http://iswix.codeplex.com/) that makes this as easy as right click select CommonAppDataFolder  right click new subfolder followed by typing the name and then dragging your content into that folder and clicking save.